# How to express relational algebra about join with on pharse?

Tags: hive, hiveql, relational-algebra

I don't know how to express relational algebra about SQL Query(In fact HiveQL Query) like below:

```
SELECT a0.subject FROM ( SELECT subject FROM table_name WHERE predicate='headOf'
and object='Department8' ) a0 JOIN ( SELECT subject FROM table_name WHERE
predicate='teacherOf' and object='GraduateCourse6' ) a1 on a0.subject = a1.subject;
```

I want to know relational algebra about this query.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What is your problem?

Comment: This wikipedia link may be useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra